# Load Javascript code within iframe of Article edit

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, theming, javascript

I am trying to enhance a module [CKEditor Responsive Plugin](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_responsive_plugin). I am basically looking to make the adjacent divs of equal heights by running a javascript code, this is the code:

```
/* From: https://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc */
/* Thanks to CSS Tricks for pointing out this bit of jQuery
http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/
It's been modified into a function called at page load and then each time the page is resized. One large modification was to remove the set height before each new calculation. */

(function ($) {
 equalheight = function(container){

 var currentTallest = 0,
 currentRowStart = 0,
 rowDivs = new Array(),
 $el,
 topPosition = 0;
 $(container).each(function() {

                   $el = $(this);
                   $($el).height('auto')
                   topPostion = $el.position().top;

                   if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
                   for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
                   rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
                   }
                   rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
                   currentRowStart = topPostion;
                   currentTallest = $el.height();
                   rowDivs.push($el);
                   } else {
                   rowDivs.push($el);
                   currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
                   }
                   for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
                   rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
                   }
                   });
 }

 $(document).load(function() {
                  equalheight('.equal_heights');
                  });

 $(window).resize(function(){
                  equalheight('.equal_heights');
                  });
})(jQuery);
```

I am loading this into the module using the following line:

```
// Raj:
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'ckeditor_responsive_plugin') . '/js/equal_heights.js');
```

in the `.module` file `ckeditor_responsive_plugin.module`:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Hooks implementations.
 */

/**
 * Add the basepath to the Drupal.settings js object.
 * Implements hook_page_build().
 *
 * @param array $page
 *    Page array.
 */
function ckeditor_responsive_plugin_page_build(array &$page) {

  $module_base_path = url( drupal_get_path('module', 'ckeditor_responsive_plugin'),
    array(
      'absolute'=>true,
    )
  );

  $my_settings = array(
    'basePath' => $module_base_path,
  );
  drupal_add_js(array('ckeditor_responsive_plugin' => $my_settings), 'setting');

// Raj:
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'ckeditor_responsive_plugin') . '/js/equal_heights.js');
}

/**
 * Define the CKEditor plugin.
 * Implements hook_ckeditor_plugin().
 *
 * @return array
 *   CKEditor settings.
 */
function ckeditor_responsive_plugin_ckeditor_plugin() {
  return array(
    'responsivness' => array(
      'name' => 'responsivness',
      'desc' => t('CKEditor Responsive Plugin : Allow to insert responsive areas'),
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'ckeditor_responsive_plugin') . '/responsivness/',
      'buttons' => array(
        'responsivness' => array(
          'icon' => 'images/responsivness.png',
          'label' => t('Add responsive area'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Everything is working in the article view, however, when I "edit" the article, the article contents are loaded into iframe and that is where things start breaking.

Live article view:
[image]
`equal_heights` is the class on which the height is explicitly set by javascript.

Now, when user tries to edit it, the whole article related HTML is loaded as an iframe and as a result, I think, the javascript is not able to get the elements within the iframe. This is what is happening:

[image]

I have set a red background for the `equal_heights` divs to show the difference in both mode.

I suspect that there has to be a hook like:

```
function ckeditor_responsive_plugin_page_build(array &$page)
```

which will help me load the javascript for edit mode, but I am not able to figure it out.

Looking forward for some help and advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code needs to access the CKEDITOR iframe. How?

```
// some code to grab the element with the CKEditor iframe
// [0] is use to get the element, not the jQuery wrapper...
var CKEDITORiframeDOM = jQuery('.cke_contents iframe')[0].contentDocument
```

With CKEDITORiframeDOM you can access all the elements on the iframe... and use jQuery too.

```
var $CKEDITORiframe = jQuery(CKEDITORiframeDOM);
```

Now to find an element in your iframe is simple...

```
console.log($CKEDITORiframe.find('p').text());
```

Finally you need to write a bit of JS code in order to make your script work also with the elements inside the iframe.

Hope that helps!

PD: In some browsers you will need to use document instead of contentDocument.

PD2: Want more info about iframe access with JS? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451208/access-iframe-elements-in-javascript